# GIF image issues with PictureBoxes

Tags: c#, mdi

I am a newbie here and I really appreciate your help.

I am creating a MDI project in Visual C#. There is 1 Child Form, while 1 Parent Form can hold maximum of 4 Child Forms from the same type. In each of the child form, there are 150 PictureBoxes, so If I run my Program, it will have a total of 600 PictureBoxes.

Now I want to Load a moving image to EVERY PictureBoxes. The question is, why only some of them do the animation? Is it the control focus problem( because when I click on one of the form child, ALL 150 Pictureboxes in that form and SOME from other form do the animation), or other problem maybe?

Comment: Can you provide more info? are all of them of the same format?

Comment: yes, everyone of them is .gif format, same size, the exact same picture.

Comment: Too many images of course.  Look at your UI thread, it is probably burning 100% core.  Painting like a mother but never being able to keep up.